# Simple HTML DOM, finding links recurssively

Tags: php, recursion, simple-html-dom

I am using [simple html dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to find links on a certain page using:

```
// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

This find all the links on the page, however i want to be able to go to found links
as well and find links *inside* those found links recursively for example to level 5.

Any idea of how to go about?

Comment: What would be your desired outcome, as the above would find links within links?

Comment: @Robert: Yeah links inside links recurssively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive function and keep track of the depth:

```
function findLinks($url, $depth, $maxDepth) {
  // fetch $url and parse it
  // ...
  if ($depth <= $maxDepth)
    foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
      findLinks($element->href, $depth + 1, $maxDepth);
}
```

And you would start by calling something like `findLinks($rootUrl, 1, 5)`.

Comment: Yea im struggling to understand the logic of this as well.

Comment: @Murilo: Care to read the commented line? You need to fetch `$url` yourself -- I have no idea where you're getting the file from.

Comment: This would be recursive pages not recursive elements within a single page, He has 1 page and he wants to get all links and there depth within the DOM I believe.

Comment: @RobertPitt: That doesn't make any sense -- you can't have "links within links" in a valid HTML page.

Comment: @casablanca: I meant when you found links on a page, i should be able to visit found links and then find other links inside those and so on. Your code makes sense though.

Comment: @casablanca, My apologies for the misunderstanding, your absolutely correct and I miss interpreted the original question. +1

Answer (score 1):

In the past I did need a similar feature. What you can do is use mysql to store your links.

In my case I had a *todo* table and a *pages* table. Seed your *todo* table with some url's you want to spider.

What I used to do was to get the page info I need (plaintext and title) and store this in a mysql db *pages*. Then I used to loop through the links and add them to the *todo* table. The last step was to remove the current page from my todo list then loop over..

```
grab a url from todo loop 
{ 
   get current page title and plaintext store it in pages table
   loop through links Add found links to todo table
   remove current page from todo 
}
```